# Facebook-like friends listing

Tags: html, css

I want to design my a friends list page that is almost identical to Facebook's, how there is a thumbmail image with some text beside it (that is aligned with the top of the graphic), and then surrounded by a gentle box.

Can someone provide some sample HTML/CSS for this?

Comment: Why not just the appropriate web developer tool for your browser (e.g. Firebug) to inspect the HTML and CSS used by Facebook directly?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you use Firefox browser and install the Firebug plug-in. Then inspect whatever you want to `plagiarise` from wherever you like. Firebug is a must-have if you're into web development :)

Comment: How do you use this thing? The CSS is so short are you sure it's capturing everything?

Comment: If your Firebug is installed and enabled then you can go to the particular element on the page you intend to `inspect` and press Ctrl+Shift+C (turn on fb's inspect function), click on the element and look at the CSS styles applied to it in the right-hand pane.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at and learning from their html/css via Firebug is probably the best in the long run, but this breakdown might also be useful: [How to Style an Application Like Facebook](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-style-an-application-like-facebook).